# AttributeError: module 'geopandas' has no attribute 'GeoDataFrame'

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, attributeerror, geopandas

I'm getting this AttributeError in Jupyter Notebook. I tried install last version of geopandas again but it does not work. How can I fix it?

```
df = pd.read_csv('veriler.txt', sep=';')
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    df, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude))
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-c1083cdaa3c9> in <module>
----> 1 gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
      2     df, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude))

AttributeError: module 'geopandas' has no attribute 'GeoDataFrame'
```